# Failing to create a window in GLFW C++

Tags: c++, glfw

Some background if you care/if it helps. I am pretty knew to programming and C++, I tried to learn it a couple times before but couldn't stay interested. As I couldn't think of an interesting project to do as I learn. Eventually I thought of making a game engine(dumb idea for a noob, but it will be a good learning experience and I'm interested in doing it.), so I searched for a series on making one to get an idea and found TheChernoProject's series and here I am.

I'm trying to make a make a window in GLFW and C++ but it keeps failing, I have no idea what to do.

Main.cpp

```
#include "src\graphics\window.h"


int main() {

using namespace tmge;
using namespace graphics;

Window window("Test", 1280, 720);

while (!window.windowClosed()) {
    window.update();
}


return 0;
}
```

Window.h

```
#pragma once

#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace tmge { namespace graphics {

class Window {

private:
    GLFWwindow *privateWindow;
    int privateWidth, privateHeight;
    const char *privateTitle;
    bool privateWindowClosed();
public:
    Window(const char *title, int width, int height);
    ~Window();
    bool init();
    void update() const;
    bool windowClosed() const;
};


} }
```

Window.cpp

```
#include "window.h"

namespace tmge { namespace graphics {

Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height) {
    privateTitle = title;
    privateWidth = width;
    privateHeight = height;
    if (!init()) {
        glfwTerminate();
    }
}

Window::~Window() {
    glfwTerminate();
}

bool Window::init() {
    if (!glfwInit) {
        std::cout << "GLFW initialaztion failed" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    privateWindow = glfwCreateWindow(privateWidth, privateHeight, privateTitle, NULL, NULL);
    if (!privateWindow) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(privateWindow);
    return true;

}

bool Window::windowClosed() const{
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(privateWindow);
}

void Window::update() const{
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(privateWindow);
}

} }
```

Comment: Is `if (!glfwInit)` meant to be a function call? You need `()` for that.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks